# Differential Equation solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hello I solved the differential equation $$x'=-\frac{x}{t}+\ln(t)$$ and my solution was

$$x=-ct+\frac{t\ln^2 t}{2}$$

However if I type this equation in Wolfram Alpha, the solution is different from mine. Can someone please verify my answer or correct me?

Thanks, Ciwan

Comment: Plug your solution in the equation !

Comment: For your solution you need the other sign, as $(\frac{x}{t})'=\frac{x'}t-\frac{x}{t^2}$, so that you would need $x'=+\frac{x}{t}+...$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x'=-\frac{x}{t}+\ln(t)\implies t x'+x=t\ln (t) \implies t dx + x dt= t\ln (t) dt$

Integrating,

$xt=\int t\ln (t) dt=\ln (t) \int t dt -\int[\frac{d}{dt} \ln(t) \int t dt] dt= \frac{t^2}{2}\ln(t)-\int \frac{1}{t} \frac{t^2}{2} dt=\frac{t^2}{2}\ln(t)-\frac{t^2}{4}+c$

$\implies x=\frac{t}{2}\ln(t)-\frac{t}{4}+ct^{-1}$